# How do I get the custom attributes of a method from Action<T>?

Tags: c#, reflection

How can I get the custom attributes of a method from a `Action<T>` delegate?

Example:

```
//simple custom attribute
public class StatusAttribute : Attribute
{

    public string Message { get; set; } = string.Empty;
}

// an extension methodto wrap MethodInfo.GetCustomAttributes(Type, Bool) with
// generics for the custom Attribute type
public static class MethodInfoExtentions
{
    public static IEnumerable<TAttribute> GetCustomAttributes<TAttribute>(this MethodInfo methodInfo, bool inherit) where TAttribute : Attribute
    {
        object[] attributeObjects = methodInfo.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(TAttribute), inherit);
        return attributeObjects.Cast<TAttribute>();
    }
}

// test class with a test method to implment the custom attribute
public class Foo
{
    [Status(Message="I'm doing something")]
    public void DoSomething()
    {
        // code would go here       
    }
}

// creates an action and attempts to get the attribute on the action
private void CallDoSomething()
{
    Action<Foo> myAction = new Action<Foo>(m => m.DoSomething());
    IEnumerable<StatusAttribute> statusAttributes = myAction.Method.GetCustomAttributes<StatusAttribute>(true);

    // Status Attributes count = 0? Why?
}
```

I realize I could do this by using reflection on Foo, but for what I'm trying to create I have to use an `Action<T>`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The problem is that the action doesn't directly point at `Foo.DoSomething`. It points at a compiler-generated method of the form:

```
private static void <>__a(Foo m)
{
    m.DoSomething();
}
```

One option here would be to change it to an `Expression<Action<T>>`, then you can dissect the expression tree afterwards and extract the attributes:

```
Expression<Action<Foo>> myAction = m => m.DoSomething();
var method = ((MethodCallExpression)myAction.Body).Method;
var statusAttributes = method.GetCustomAttributes<StatusAttribute>(true);
int count = statusAttributes.Count(); // = 1
```

Answer (score 3):

The issue is that the lambda `m => m.DoSomething()` is **not** the same as `DoSomething`. It is a lambda expression which gets compiled into a method call on a compiler-generated method, possibly using a compiler-generated type (though maybe not the latter, since there are no captured local variables).

A very verbose way of getting an `Action<Foo>` from an instance (non-static) method of the `Foo` type is this:

```
var myAction = (Action<Foo>)Delegate.CreateDelegate(
    typeof(Action<Foo>),
    null, // treat method as static, even though it's not
    typeof(Foo).GetMethod("DoSomething", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public)
);
```

Obviously, that is far from ideal and probably in fact *useless* in your case; but it's worth knowing ;)

---

**Update**: Actually, it just occurred to me you could write a quick extension method to make this easy for *any* instance method that you want to wrap as a static method (and maintain the "correct" `MethodInfo`):

```
public static class ActionEx
{
    public static Action<T> ToStaticMethod<T>(this Action action)
    {
        if (!(action.Target is T))
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("Blah blah blah.");
        }

        return (Action<T>)Delegate.CreateDelegate(
            typeof(Action<T>),
            null,
            action.Method
        );
    }
}
```

This would allow you to do:

```
Action<Foo> myAction = new Action(new Foo().DoSomething).ToStaticMethod<Foo>();
```

Admittedly, it's not as nice as `m => m.DoSomething()`; but it *does* give you an `Action<T>` whose `Method` property actually references the `DoSomething` method directly.

---

Alternately, instead of an `Action<T>`, you could use an `Expression<Action<T>>` and get the `MethodInfo` from that. Note that the syntax looks just the same in this case:

```
Action<Foo> myAction = m => m.DoSomething();
Expression<Action<Foo>> myExpression = m => m.DoSomething();
```

But that is a tricky proposition since an arbitrary `Expression<Action<T>>` is not guaranteed to be as simple as just `m => m.DoSomething()`.

Answer (score -1):

None of previous answers (except @Marc Gravell♦ 's which has no user's code) seems to be compilable :)

So I would propose mine:

```
private static void CallDoSomething()
{
    var f = new Foo();
    Action myAction = f.DoSomething;
    IEnumerable<StatusAttribute> statusAttributes = myAction.Method.GetCustomAttributes<StatusAttribute>(true);
}
```

Comment: The problem here is that you must wrap the method to a delegate. You could declare the variable `myAction` as a `Delegate`-typed. However, in this case you must instantiate a `Delegate` type (such as `Action`), so it doesn't make sense. Also, there are many compilable solutions! -1 for that.