# Get custom attribute of method executed in action

Tags: c#, lambda, action

Here is my example metod

```
[TestStep("Do something")]
private void DoSomething()
{   
}
```

Each method which looks like the one above is executed in a way which requires logging the method parameters:

```
private void LogStep(Action action)
{
    string stepName = "[" + action.Method.Name + "] ";
    var descr = Attribute.GetCustomAttribute(action.Method, typeof(TestStepAttribute)) as TestStepAttribute;

    if (descr == null)
    {
        this.TestLog.AddWarningMessage(
            (action.Method.DeclaringType == null ? string.Empty : action.Method.DeclaringType.FullName + ".") + action.Method.Name
            + ": missing description");

        return;
    }

    stepName += descr.Description;

    this.TestLog.EndGroup();

    this.TestLog.BeginGroup(stepName);
}
```

And here I come with a problem. Executing LogStep like

```
LogStep(DoSomething)
```

works perfectly, but when I execute it using lambda expression

```
LogStep(() => DoSomething())
```

It tells me that there are no attributes of type `TestStepAttribute` in that `Action`.

At first glance it seems to be similar to [How do I get the custom attributes of a method from Action<T>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4822461/how-do-i-get-the-custom-attributes-of-a-method-from-actiont) but in my case I neither can change type of `Action` to `Expression<Action>` nor I know the method name.

Any suggestion'd be helpful.

Comment: Write a version of the method that accepts an expression-tree (which, unlike a delegate, is easily inspectable). Otherwise, you're out of luck unless you want to start digging into IL op-codes.

Comment: Shouldn't your first execution example be `LogStep(DoSomething)`? *(Without the "()")*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you execute it using a lambda expression, the lambda expression itself is the method. It happens that in its body there is a method call, but there could be something else there (like `new object()`). The only way to get access to the attributes of this inner method is to pass the lambda expression as `Expression` and to analyze the expression.

In order to handle both cases you will need two overloads of `LogStep`. However, you cannot have `LogStep(Action)` and `LogStep(Expression<Action>)` as overloads at the same time as the calls would be ambiguous. But it would work if one of them was `LogStep(Delegate)`.

```
private void LogStep(Delegate action)
{
    var attr = (TestStepAttribute)Attribute
        .GetCustomAttribute(action.Method, typeof(TestStepAttribute));
    Console.WriteLine("LogStep(Delegate action):  " + attr?.Description);
}

private void LogStep(Expression<Action> actionExpr)
{
    string descr = null;
    var methodCall = actionExpr.Body as MethodCallExpression;
    if (methodCall != null) {
        var attribs = methodCall.Method.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(TestStepAttribute), true);
        if (attribs.Length > 0) {
            descr = ((TestStepAttribute)attribs[0]).Description;
        }
    }
    Console.WriteLine("LogStep(Expression<Action> actionExpr):  " + descr);
}
```

Tests:

```
LogStep(new Action(DoSomething)); // new Action() Is required here. Calls first overlaod.
LogStep(() => DoSomething()); // Calls second overload.
LogStep(() => new object());  // Calls second overload.
```

Note that you can compile and execute lambda expressions, in case you need to execute the method.

Answer (score 2):

> works perfectly, but when I execute it using lambda expression
>
> LogStep(() => DoSomething()) It tells me that there are no attributes
>   of type TestStepAttribute in that Action.

Well of course won't find any attributes because you are passing a lambda expression which is basically a method and in that method you pass your method DoSomething() and the check is done on the lambda expression.

Comment: I can't agree with you more. Question is how to retrieve that attribute from the inner method

Answer (score 1):

Lambda expression is just another method. When you look at `action.Method`, that's the method you get (and `action.Target` will contain a closure, if any).

In the end, all you have is:

```
void SomeAnonymousMethod()
{
  DoSomething();
}
```

To get to the method actually being called, you'd have to decompile the anonymous method first. And of course, you're probably using the lambda syntax to pass arguments while still working with a paremeter-less action, where it gets even crazier:

```
class SomeClosure
{
  string argument1;
  int argument2;

  void AnonymousMethod()
  {
    var data = GetSomeData(argument2);

    DoSomething(data, argument1);
  }
}
```

How do you even *tell* that `DoSomething` is the method you need metadata of?

There isn't a way around this using lambda expressions. Fortunately, it doesn't seem you actually need that anyway, since you're never calling the argument. Instead of using `Action`, just use `Delegate`, and you can pass whatever method you need directly:

```
void DoSomething(string something, string otherThing)
{
  ... // Not important
}

void LogStep(Delegate someDelegate)
{
  ... // Exactly as before
}

LogStep((Action<string, string>)DoSomething);
```

You do have to manually cast at the invocation, sadly, otherwise the compiler gives you an error; you can keep the same signature for the `LogStep` method itself, though. Alternatively, you could use a simple T4 template to create multiple overloads of the `LogStep` method so that you can avoid the explicit cast in your hand-written code.